# Google Maps API V3 "Overview" option

Tags: google-maps

Google Maps API V3 doesn't support the V2 GOverviewMapControl option, yet. I've come across a piece of code at http://dl.google.com/io/2009/pres/Th_1045_Maps_API_Mobile.pdf , silde 19, that gives the code to display the smaller map, but not the draggable, semi-transparent blue box that you generally see here. It's possible, but unofrtunately the code is 'ellided'. Anyone have any ideas how to generate this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the `overlayMap`, add a [draggable marker](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/overlays.html#Draggable_Markers) to display the frame of the `RectangleOverlay`, and a non-draggable marker to display the semi-transparent box itself.  Then, add bindings to some of [the maps' events](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/reference.html#Map) to update size and position of the markers, i.e. the maps' `bounds_changed`, `drag`, and/or `center_changed` events. Finally, update the location of the maps when the frame is dragged by binding a function to its `dragend` event.

Comment: Thanks to your suggestions, and my own increasing experience of Google Maps API v3, I've actually now written my own open source plug-in for this and it's available at http://www.drcoen.com/2010/10/google-maps-api-v3-overview-control/ or on github at https://github.com/drcoen/Google-Maps-API-V3-Overview-Control .

Answer (score 3):

This is how it works out of the box in Maps v3:

```
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    overviewMapControl: true,
    overviewMapControlOptions: {opened: true}
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
}
```

Please note the last two properties of the mapOptions object. They do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I am using v3 right now and the overviewMapControl seems to work. Can't find any documentation on it yet.

overviewMapControl: true

Then you see a small arrow in the right hand side of your map. Click will open it. Can't figure out how to trigger this click with javascript (jquery) doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-v3-overviewmapcontrol It's an open-source project to approximate the functionality of v2's GOverviewMapControl.

Comment: I actually did end up totally mimicing the OverviewMap in V3 and getting the draggable blue box to work. However, I ended up ditching it as the overview map still contained the Google logo and reference to the map provider, which didn't look great in the small overlay window. Do you know if the project you've mentioned here has manage to overcome that issue?

Comment: Not yet. But I am the project's primary dev, and I think I'll see if I can't track down someone on the Maps API team and/or Google Legal to see about getting permission to do just that.